# Projecting Skolem's Paradox Upwards

Tags: elementary-set-theory, model-theory, diagonalization, infinity

My understanding of the resolution of Skolem's Paradox is that although in a countable model of ZFC there does not exist a bijection between a countable set and its powerset, we can still construct a bijection working outside the model which is a bijection.

But given this, why is there a reason to believe that this cannot always be done for any model? In other words, how do we know that "uncountable" ever means something other than undefinable and that Cantor's Theorem points to combinatorial properties of levels of infinity rather than just an inherent limitation of definable functions, making everything essentially $\aleph_0$?

**EDIT**

I realize I probably wasn't clear in what I was asking originally so I'll try again: From what I've learned so far about set theory it seems that bijections within a model can fail for possibly one of two reasons:

- **Case I:** There are "more" elements in one set than the other. This certainly happens with finite sets of different cardinalities and I see this also in the presentation of the diagonal argument on a proposed enumeration of the real numbers in the interval $(0,1)$
- **Case II:** The sets are both subsets (at least in an informal sense) of countable sets but a bijection is ruled out for logical reasons: Like if we make a Godel numbering on the von Neumann integers and set $A$ equal to the subset of Godel numbers of all sentences true in that given model. Then $A$ is a subset of a countable set but there can't be a bijection between it and all the von Neumann integers because that would violate Tarski's Theorem. (or so I think). This would also be the case in a countable model, where a countable set and its powerset are both countable viewed externally but no bijection exists internally because of Cantor's Theorem.

So my question is how do we know that Case I is a real possibility (besides for finite sets or a finite and infinite set)? In other words, could it  be that cardinal numbers greater than $\aleph_0$ just exist because of extensions of Case II above and aren't really new mathematical objects in their own right?

Hopefully this is clearer, but I'll stop if not.

Comment: This *can* be done for any model. For any infinite set $X$ in any model $V$ of ZFC, there is a forcing extension of $V$ in which $X$ is countable.

Comment: @AlexKruckman You have to be a bit careful there. Strictly speaking, that statement isn't true - or more precisely, it's not a theorem of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and indeed $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + [reasonable hypotheses] disproves it (unless by "forcing extension" you allow Boolean-valued models as well). As long as we assume a "true" background universe within which everything takes place, there will be such a thing as "truly uncountable" - it will just be potentially hard to detect.

Comment: @AlexKruckman To be precise, if $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ and $x\in M$ then we do indeed have $M\models(\Vdash_{Col(\omega,x)^M}$ "$x$ is countable"). However, a (non-Boolean-valued) "real" $Col(\omega,x)$-generic extension of $M$ isn't guaranteed to exist if $M$ isn't countable to begin with.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ok, clearly there are subtleties here I'm not aware of. Why can't you do the usual thing of getting a Boolean valued model and then quotienting by an ultrafilter to get a "real" model? What are the [reasonable hypotheses]? "There is a truly uncountable, but it's potentially hard to detect" sounds interesting - you should write an answer!

Comment: @AlexKruckman "Why can't you do the usual thing of getting a Boolean valued model and then quotienting by an ultrafilter to get a "real" model?" You can do that, but I wouldn't call that a "forcing extension" - in my mind, a forcing extension has to literally be "$M[G]$" for $G$ a generic-over-$M$ filter. In particular, the ordinals of $M$ and $M[G]$ have to coincide, $\omega^M$ has to be the same as $\omega^{M[G]}$ *(which means, relevantly, that if $M$ is an $\omega$-model, $M[G]$ can't think something truly uncountable is countable)*, etc. I don't think we're disagreeing substantively here.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah, ok, good. So I'm not crazy: it's true that if $M$ is a model of ZFC which thinks $x$ is infinite, then $M$ embeds in $M'$ which is a model of ZFC and thinks $x$ is countable. Further, we can take $M'$ to be a quotient of a boolean valued model based on $M$. I just maybe shouldn't call such an $M'$ a forcing extension of $M$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Whoa, way above my pay grade. I was hoping for an answer that would address whether the notion of uncountable set dominance should ever be thought of in terms of the intuitive notion of "having more elements than can be listed" (as is the case with the standard presentation of Cantor's Theorem) or just in terms of the dry formalism of the non-existence of a bijection. I know next to nothing about forcing but I assume the models you and Noah are discussing must be uncountable so I don't see how that helps.

Comment: What is the difference between "$X$ more elements than can be listed" and "there is no bijection from $X$ to $\mathbb{N}$"? It can be helpful to think about things in intuitive ways, but if you want to prove things at the end of the day, you have to use  precise definitions and rigorous arguments - what you might describe as "dry formalism". Anyway, it's not clear to me what your actual question is. Maybe you can edit the question and clarify.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks. I just tried an edit. Hopefully better and not worse